# delayed_job_config.rb undefined method with log ration rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, logging, delayed-job

I use rails 3.2.8 and I need make log rotation on development and production env:

I have added to `development.rb` and production.rb the next for log rotation:

```
config.logger = Logger.new("#{Rails.root.to_s}/log/development.log", 2, 10.megabytes)
config.logger = Logger.new("#{Rails.root.to_s}/log/production.log", 2, 10.megabytes)
```

I need use delayed_job gem and I get this is my `delayed_job_config.rb:`

```
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 2
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = !Rails.env.test?
Delayed::Worker.logger = Rails.logger
Delayed::Worker.logger.auto_flushing = true
```

I get the next error:

```
...config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb:4:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `auto_flushing=' for #<Logger:0xbe59ba0> (NoMethodError)
```

I need use log rotation because these files grow very fast and and I have to manually delete.

**How can I fix this error? and add log rotation to both env?**

Thank you

Comment: Don't know if you are using Heroku, but I got this same error and found that simply by removing the line `Delayed::Worker.logger.auto_flushing = true` it seemed to work fine